# Am getting server error when i use the call toOthers in laravel broadcast

Tags: laravel

Announce that new event have been posted

Please, I have this below if I use event() it works fine but if I add `toOthers` it gives me an error why?

```php
Route::post('/messages', function(){
    $user = Auth::user();

    $message = $user->messages()->create([
        'message' => request()->get('message')
    ]);

    //Announce that new event have been posted
    broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user))->toOthers;

    return ['status' => 'OK'];

})->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 1):

`toOthers()` is a function not a property

```php
broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user))->toOthers();
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting#only-to-others)

However, the `broadcast` function also exposes the `toOthers` method which allows you to exclude the current user from the broadcast's recipients:

```php
broadcast(new ShippingStatusUpdated($update))->toOthers();
```

From [the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/PendingBroadcast.php#L41) in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/PendingBroadcast.php` Line 41

```php
public function toOthers()
{
    if (method_exists($this->event, 'dontBroadcastToCurrentUser')) {
        $this->event->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Added this toOthers();

broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user))->toOthers();

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('/messages', function(){

    $user = Auth::user();
    $message = $user->messages()->create([
        'message' => request()->get('message')
    ]);    

    broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user))->toOthers();

    return ['status' => 'OK'];
})->middleware('auth');
```